# Sidebar Showing outside of a div on tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I just finished coding a theme and everything as far as the coding and overall appearance is great except for one thing. So when I go to the inbox page or any page where the content is shorter than the overall sidebar height, my sidebar div seems to go outside my container div. Here's an example here
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB1yx.png).
Here's the coding structure css & html.

```
.sidebar {
    width:310px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left: 590px;
    position: absolute;

.wrap {
    width: 920px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background:{color:content background};
    padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    position: relative;

}

.content {
    margin-top:30px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left:20px;

}

<div class="wrap"> <!--CONTAINER-->

<div class="topbar"> <!--TOP LINKS-->
<div id="title">{title}</div>
<div class="links">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/ask">Inbox</a>
    <a href="/archive">Archive</a>
    <a href="{text:link 1 url}">{text:link 1 title}</a>
    <a href="{text:link 2 url}">{text:link 2 title}</a>

     <!--DO NOT REMOVE CREDIT!!!-->
    <a href="http://ixaathemes.tumblr.com/">Theme</a>
     <!--DO NOT REMOVE CREDIT!!!-->

</div> <!--TOP LINKS-->


</div>

<div class="header">
<img src="{image:header}">
</div>

<div class="sidebar">  <!--SIDEBAR CONTENT. THIS IS WHERE THE SIDEBOXES ARE WHERE YOU CAN MANUALLY ADD THE CONTENTS-->



    <!-- DESCRIPTION BOX -->

<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Welcome</div>
<div class="sideimg"><img src="{image:sidebar}"></div>
    <div class="description">{Description}</div>
</div>

    <!-- NAVIGATION LINKS -->
{block:ifextralinks}
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Navigation Links</div>
<div class="morelinks">
    {block:ifCustomLink1}<a href="{text:CustomLink1URL}">{text:CustomLink1Name}</a>{/block:ifCustomLink1}
    {block:ifCustomLink2}<a href="{text:CustomLink2URL}">{text:CustomLink2Name}</a>{/block:ifCustomLink2}
    {block:ifCustomLink3}<a href="{text:CustomLink3URL}">{text:CustomLink3Name}</a>{/block:ifCustomLink3}
    {block:ifCustomLink4}<a href="{text:CustomLink4URL}">{text:CustomLink4Name}</a>{/block:ifCustomLink4}
    {block:ifCustomLink5}<a href="{text:CustomLink5URL}">{text:CustomLink5Name}</a>{/block:ifCustomLink5}
    {block:ifCustomLink6}<a href="{text:CustomLink6URL}">{text:CustomLink6Name}</a>{/block:ifCustomLink6}
</div>
</div>
{/block:ifextralinks}

    <!-- UPCOMING EVENTS -->
{block:ifevents}  
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Upcoming events</div>

    <div class="events">

<!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL ADD YOUR UPCOMING EVENTS IF YOU PLEASE. if you would like to add more just copy the code below:

<tr>
<td>
<div class="date">Event date here</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="e">Event info here</div>
</td>
</tr>

make sure to past it right about the 'event end'
-->

<table style="width:100%">

<!-- events box start -->

<tr>
<td>
<div class="date">November 12</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="e">Event: One</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="date">November 13</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="e">Event: two</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="date">November 14</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="e">Event: three</div>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<div class="date">November 14</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="e">Event: four</div>
</td>
</tr>

<!-- events box start -->
</table>
</div></div>
{/block:ifevents}  

    <!-- PROJECTS -->
{block:ifprojects}
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Projects</div>

    <div class="projects">

    <!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU WILL ADD THE PROJECTS THAT CORRESPOND WITH THE THEME OF YOUR FANSITE BLOG. iF YOU WOULD LIKETO ADD MORE JUST COPY THE CODE BELOW:

     <tr>
<td style="width:30px">          
           <img src="IMAGE URL">
</td>
<td>
                <div class="pinfo">
                <b>Title:</b><br>
                <l1>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info</div>
                </l1>
</td>
 </tr>

 MAKE SURE TO PASTE IT RIGHT ABOVE THE 'PROJECTS END'
    -->

 <table style="margin-top:0px; width:100%">

  <!-- PROJECTS START-->

 <tr>
<td style="width:30px">          
           <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/pbhn8p5/BPwo9x2yv/ject-5.png">
</td>
<td>
                <div class="pinfo">
                <b>Title:</b><br>
                <l1>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info</div>
                </l1>
</td>
 </tr>              

 <tr>
<td style="width:30px">                
               <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/pbhn8p5/AoQo9x30n/ject-6.png">
</td>
<td>
                <div class="pinfo">
                <b>Title:</b><br>
                <l1>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info</div>
                </l1>
</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
<td style="width:30px">                
                          <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/pbhn8p5/t5so9x315/ject-7.png">
</td>
<td>
                <div class="pinfo">
                <b>Title:</b><br>
                <l1>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info<br>
                <b>Info</b>: Info</div>
                </l1>
</td>
 </tr>

  <!-- PROGECTS END-->
 </table>              

               </div></div>
{/block:ifprojects}

    <!-- MEMBERS -->
{block:ifmembers}  
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Members</div>

     <!-- THIS IS BASICALLY SET UP FOR A GROUP BLOG SCENARIO. BASICALLY THE BLOGGER (YOU) GIVE PERMISSION FOR OTHER PEOPLE TO HAVE ACCESS TO THIS BLOG. FOR MORE INFORMATION ON HOW TO SET THIS UP CHECK OUT THIS WEBSITE BELOW

   http://smallbusiness.chron.com/set-up-admins-tumblr-34947.html  

    SO TO PUT IT SIMPLY YOU DON'T EDIT THIS BOX LIKE YOU WOULD THE OTHERS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING.
     -->


    {block:GroupMembers}
<table style="margin-top:0px; padding: 10px;">
{block:GroupMember}
<tr>
<td style="width:40px;">
<img src="{GroupMemberPortraitURL-40}" width="40px;" height="40px;" style="margin-right: 10px; padding:5px;">  
</td>
<td style="width:290px; height:auto;">
<div id="m" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
<a href="{GroupMemberURL}" style="color:{color:desc link};">{GroupMemberName}</a><br>{GroupMemberTitle}</div>

</tr>
{/block:GroupMember}
</table>
{/block:GroupMembers}
</div>
{/block:ifmembers}

  <!-- UPDATES BOX -->
{block:ifupdates}
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Updates</div>

    <div class="up">

<!-- THIS IS THE UPDATES TAP WHERE YOU CAN PLACE ALL OF YOUR RECORDS OF YOUR RECENT BLOG-RELATED UPDATES. IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO ADD MORE UPDATES THEN YOU CAN JUST COPY THE CODE BELOW:

<tr>
<td><div class="update">date</div></td>
<td><div class="upinfo">update</div></td>
</tr>

MAKE SURE TO PASTE THE CODE RIGHT ABOUT THE 'UPDATES END'

-->

<table style="width:100%">

  <!-- UPDATES START -->

<tr>
<td><div class="update">11.12:</div></td>
<td><div class="upinfo">update one</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="update">11.13:</div></td>
<td><div class="upinfo">update one</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="update">11.14:</div></td>
<td><div class="upinfo">update one</div></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><div class="update">11.15:</div></td>
<td><div class="upinfo">update one</div></td>
</tr>

  <!-- UPDATES END -->
</table>
</div>        
</div>
{/block:ifupdates}

    <!-- AFFILIATES -->
{block:ifaffiliates}
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Affiliates</div>

    <div class="affiliates">

<!-- THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN ADD THE IMAGES OF THE SISTER BLOG IN WHICH YOUR FANSITE IS AFFILIATED WITH. IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO ADD MORE PICTURES THEN JUST CODY THE CODE BELOW

        <a href="/" title="visit blog"><img src="IMAGE URL"/></a>

MAKE SURE TO PASTE THE CODE RIGHT ABOVE THE 'AFFILIATES END'
-->

<!-- AFFILIATES START-->

        <a href="/" title="apply"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/7r3q3uq/MmIo6iq7n/ject-1.png"/></a>
        <a href="/" title="apply"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/7r3q3uq/lado6ipym/ject-2.png"/></a>
        <a href="/" title="apply"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/7r3q3uq/QrJo6ipyy/ject-3.png"/></a>
        <a href="/" title="apply"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/7r3q3uq/L0Mo6ipz9/ject-4.png"/></a>

<!-- AFFILIATES END-->      
    </div>
</div>
{/block:ifaffiliates}

    <!-- OFFICIAL LINKS -->
{block:ifofficiallinks}    
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>Official Links</div>
    <div class="off">

<!-- THEM OFFICIAL LINKS WHICH ARE ALREADY SET UP FOR YOU IN THE EDIT THEME SECTION DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW. -->  

        <a href="{text:official link 1 url}">{text:official link 1 title} <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="float:right; color:{color:navi};"></i></a>
        <a href="{text:official link 2 url}">{text:official link 2 title} <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="float:right; color:{color:navi};"></i></a>
        <a href="{text:official link 3 url}">{text:official link 3 title} <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="float:right; color:{color:navi};"></i></a>
        <a href="{text:official link 4 url}">{text:official link 4 title} <i class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right; color:{color:navi};"></i></a>
        <a href="{text:official link 5 url}">{text:official link 5 title} <i class="fa fa-youtube-play" style="float:right; color:{color:navi};"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
{/block:ifofficiallinks}    

 <!-- BLOG INFO -->
{block:ifbloginfo}  
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>About this blog</div>
    <div class="binfo">

<!-- GENER BLOG INFO LIKE WHEN WAS IT ESTABLISHED. YOUR FREE HOSTED SCRIPTS (ONLINE USERS, BLOG VISITS, FOLLOWERS/ETC. -->  

     <b>About:</b> A fansite theme for fandom challenges, character, shipss, whatever floats your boat <br>
        <b>Admins:</b> 1 <br>
        <b>Designed by:</b> <a href="http://ixathemes.tumblr.com">ixathemes</a> @ tumblr<br>
        <b>Online:</b> <script language="JavaScript">
var ref = (''+document.referrer+'');
var w_h = window.screen.width + " x " + window.screen.height;
document.write('<script src="http://s1.freehostedscripts.net/ocounter.php?site=ID4973001&e1=ghoul &e2=ghouls &r=' + ref + '&wh=' + w_h + '"><\/script>');
</script> <br>
        <b>Visits:</b> <script language="JavaScript" src="http://s1.freehostedscripts.net/ocount.php?site=ID2955028&name=investigators"></script><br><br>

            This site claims no credit for any images posted unless it's been stated otherwise. Images and information posted on this blog are copyrighted to their respective owners.
        </div>
</div>
{/block:ifbloginfo}

    <!-- Search Bar -->
{block:ifsearch}
<div class="cat">
    <div class="cti"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right:10px; color:{color:titles};"></i>search</div>

    <div class="bsearch">

<!-- THIS IS SEARCHBAR CODE. DO NOT TOUCH PLEASE. -->  

<script language="javascript">
function send()
{document.theform.submit()}
</script>            
<form action="/search" method="get" class="sfm">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="search" id="sf"/>
    <input type="image" value="Search" src="http://static.tumblr.com/f1skqpy/Oxbn13qun/search_icon.png" id="sb"/>
</form>

<!-- THIS IS SEARCHBAR CODE. DO NOT TOUCH PLEASE. -->  
    </div>
</div>
{/block:ifsearch}
<!-- Search Bar -->

</div>  <!--SIDEBAR-->

<div class="content">  <!--CONTENT-->
{block:Posts}
 <div class="posts">  <!--POSTS-->

{block:ContentSource}
<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />
{/block:SourceLogo}
{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->
{/block:ContentSource}

<!-- {block:NoRebloggedFrom}
{block:RebloggedFrom}{ReblogParentName}{/block:RebloggedFrom}
{/block:NoRebloggedFrom} -->

{block:Text}
{block:Title}<div class="title">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}
<div class="text">{Body}</div>
{/block:Text}


{block:Photo}
{LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" width="500">{LinkCloseTag}
{/block:Photo}


{block:Photoset}
{Photoset-500}
{/block:Photoset}

{block:Quote}
<center>
<div class="quote-box">"</div>
</center>
<div class="qtline"></div>
<div class="quote">{Quote}</div>
{block:Source}<div class="qtsource"><br><center>- {Source} -</center></div>{/block:Source}
{/block:Quote}

{block:Link}
<div class="link"><a href="{URL}">{Name} »</a></div>
{block:Description}
<div class="text">{Description}</div>
{/block:Description}
{/block:Link}


{block:Chat}
{block:Title}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:Title} <div class="chat"> {block:Lines} <li class="line {Alt}"> {block:Label} <span class="label"> {Label}</span> {/block:Label}{Line}</li> {/block:Lines}</div>
{/block:Chat}


{block:Audio}
<div class="playbox"><div class="playbutton">{block:AudioPlayer}{AudioPlayerWhite}{/block:AudioPlayer}</div></div>

{block:AlbumArt}
<img src="{AlbumArtURL}" class="cover">
{/block:AlbumArt}

<div class="trackdetails"><br>
{block:TrackName}<b>Track:</b> {TrackName}{/block:TrackName}<br>
{block:Artist}<b>Artist:</b> {Artist}{/block:Artist}<br>
{block:Album}<b>Album:</b> {Album}{/block:Album}<br>
{block:PlayCount}<b>Played:</b> {PlayCountWithLabel}{/block:PlayCount}
</div>
{/block:Audio}


{block:Video}
{Video-500}
{/block:Video}


{block:Answer}
<div id="asker"><b>{Asker} asked:</b></div>
<img src="{AskerPortraitURL-64}"align="left" style="border:5px solid {color:asker portrait border}">
<div class="question">
{Question}&nbsp;</div>
<div class="answer">{Answer}</div>
{/block:Answer}

{block:IfShowCaptions}{block:Caption}<div class="text">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:IfShowCaptions}
{block:IfnotShowCaptions}
{block:PermalinkPage}{block:Caption}<div class="text">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:PermalinkPage}{/block:IfnotShowCaptions}

{block:IndexPage}
<div class="info"> <!--Permalink and Notes-->
Posted
{block:Date}
<a href="{Permalink}" title="{TimeAgo}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}{DayOfMonthSuffix}</a>
{/block:Date}
{block:NoteCount}  with <a href="{Permalink}" title="go to permalink page">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}

<font style="float:right">
{block:RebloggedFrom}
<a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentName}">via </a>
{block:ContentSource}
<a href="{ReblogRootURL}" "{ReblogRootName}" title="{ReblogRootName}">| src</a>
{/block:ContentSource}
|
{/block:RebloggedFrom}
<a href="{ReblogURL}" title="Reblog this post"> reblog</a>
</font style>
</div> <!--Permalink and Notes-->

 <!--TAGS-->
{block:ifShowTags}
{block:HasTags}<div id="tag">{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}" title="Tagged as">#{tag}</a> {/block:Tags}</div>{/block:HasTags}{/block:ifShowTags}
{block:permalinkpage}{block:ifnotShowTags}{block:HasTags}<div id="tag"> {block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}" title="Tagged as">#{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}</div>{/block:HasTags}{/block:ifnotShowTags}{/block:permalinkpage}
<!--TAGS-->

{/block:IndexPage}
</div> <!--CONTENT-->

{block:PermalinkPage} <!--PERMALINK PAGE-->
<div id="perma">
{block:Date}Posted {ShortMonth} {DayOfMonthWithZero}, {Year} @ {12Hour} {AmPm}{/block:Date}
{block:NoteCount}with {NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}{block:RebloggedFrom}
<br>
<a href="{ReblogParentURL}">via: {ReblogParentName}</a> +
<a href="{ReblogRootURL}">source: {ReblogRootName}</a>
{/block:RebloggedFrom}
<br>
{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}" title="Tagged as">#{Tag}</a> {/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}
</div>  

{block:PostNotes}
{PostNotes}
{/block:PostNotes}
{/block:PermalinkPage}
{/block:Posts} <!--PERMALINK PAGE-->

<div id="foot"> <!--PAGINATION BAR-->
<!--pagination-->
   {block:IfNotInfiniteScroll}
   {block:Pagination}
          <div id="pagination">
                {block:PreviousPage}<a href="{PreviousPage}">«</a>{/block:PreviousPage}
                {block:JumpPagination length="5"}
                {block:CurrentPage}<span class="current_page">X</span>{/block:CurrentPage}
                {block:JumpPage}<a href="{URL}">{PageNumber}</a> {/block:JumpPage}
                {/block:JumpPagination}
                {block:NextPage}<a href="{NextPage}">»</a>{/block:NextPage}
          </div>
        {/block:Pagination}
{/block:IfNotInfiniteScroll}
<!--pagination-->
</div> <!--PAGINATION BAR-->
</div> <!--CONTAINER-->
```

So I wanted to know is there any way for me to fix this because I am a theme maker and I have people coming to my inbox regarding this issue and i'd hate to respond by saying I have no idea, which could lead to them abandoning the theme because of a design flaw that I do not know how to fix. Thank you so much :)

Here is the full code [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/ePCtkR7n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser does not take into account the absolutely-positioned sidebar when calculating what the height of the container should be. So the container is too short when there is no main content or when the height of the main content is not tall enough as the sidebar.

To overcome this, you can set a minimum height for your container element equal to the height of your sidebar with jQuery, for instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".wrap").css("min-height", function(){
return $(".sidebar").innerHeight()+30;
});});
```

If your sidebar contains images I would recommend using imagesLoaded in conjunction with that so that the script accounts for heights of images instead of having them as 0 when they are loading.
We add 30 to the calculated height of the sidebar to account for the top margin.

Comment: Thank you so much and after some time I actually found a solution to this issue so I would like to thank everyone who has helped me. I greatly appreciate the time and effort :)

Answer (score 0):

set the body and html height and width to 100%

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I tried that and unfortunately it didn't work.